# my enumerable line for narcissistic numbers

Tags: ruby, enumerable

value is an integer and this is supposed to take each digit in value, raise it to the power of the number of digits in value, then sum them up.

For some reason, it works for everything but 370 and 371, at 370 i get 346 and 371 yields 347,  whats going on here?!

```
value.to_s.chars.map {|e| e.to_i }
  .inject{|sum, e| sum += e ** value.to_s.length }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the initial value for `inject`. This will work:

```
 value.to_s.chars.map {|e| e.to_i }
   .inject(0){|sum, e| sum += e ** value.to_s.length }
```

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

Comment: that works, thank you!  so the initial value refer to the index to start with?

Comment: I suggest three changes: 1) define `n = value.to_s.length` (or better, I think, `arr = value.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i); n = arr.length`) so you don't keep recalculating it for each digit of `value`; 2) remove `map` and integrate `to_i` into `inject`; and 3) change `+=` to `+`. This gives you `arr = value.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i); n = arr.length; arr.inject(0) { |sum,e| sum + e**n }`. I realize the OP did not ask for improvements, but it's educational to point them out.

Answer (score -1):

Your question has been answered, but here's another way to perform the calculation.

**Code**

```
def sum_powers(value)
  n = value.to_s.size
  n.times.reduce(0) do |t,_|
    value, d = value.divmod(10)
    t + d**n
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
sum_powers(286)
  #=> 736
```

**Explanation**

```
value = 286
n = value.to_s.size
  #=> 3
t = 0
value, d = value.divmod(10)
  #=> [28, 6]
t + d**n # replaces t
  # 0 + 6**3
  #=> 216
value, d = value.divmod(10)
  #=> [2, 8]
t + d**n # replaces t
  # 216 + 8**3
  #=> 728
value, d = value.divmod(10)
  #=> [0, 2]
t + d**n # replaces t
  # 728 + 2**3
  #=> 736
```